# Is local freeness open for curves?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, coherent-sheaves, flatness

Let $X$ be a complete nonsingular curve and $S$ a scheme over $k$ algebraically closed, and $\cal{F}$ a coherent sheaf on $X \times S$, generated by finitely many global sections and flat over $S$ (via the projection). So my question is the following: is the locus of points $s\in S$ such that $\cal{F}_s$ is locally free on $X$ open? And if so, is there an easy way to see this?

Comment: Welcome new contributor.  That is false without a hypothesis that the curve is proper.  When the curve is proper, you can prove that with “Fitting ideals”.

Comment: Thank you! Yes, the curves I'm working with are in fact proper (I edited the question). Thank you so much!

Comment: @JasonStarr Is it important that $X$ is a curve? And maybe it could be generalized to a relatively proper map $X\to S$ instead of a trivial family?

Comment: @Z.M You are correct.  The same result holds for a proper, flat morphism.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To elaborate on Jason's comment: consider a morphism of schemes $f:\mathrm{X}\rightarrow\mathrm{S}$, and an $f$-flat coherent sheaf $\mathscr{F}$ on $\mathrm{X}$. Then

(1) the singular locus $\mathrm{Sing}(\mathscr{F})$ of $\mathscr{F}$ (given by the points $x\in\mathrm{X}$ such that $\mathscr{F}$ is not locally free at $x$) is closed - if $r$ is the rank of $\mathscr{F}$, it is cut out by the $r$-th Fitting ideal sheaf of $\mathscr{F}$;

(2) $\mathscr{F}$ is locally free at $x\in\mathrm{X}$ if and only if $\mathscr{F}_{f(x)}$ is locally free at $x$, where $\mathscr{F}_{f(x)}$ denotes the restriction of $\mathscr{F}$ to $f^{-1}(f(x))$ - this follows from flatness of $\mathscr{F}$ and the Nakayama lemma.

By (1) and (2), $f(\mathrm{Sing}(\mathscr{F}))$ consists of all $s\in\mathrm{S}$ such that $\mathscr{F}_{s}$ is not locally free. If $f$ is proper, then of course the latter image is closed in $\mathrm{S}$.

Lemma 2.1.8 in *The Geometry of Moduli Spaces of Sheaves* by Huybrechts & Lehn is a good reference.

Comment: Thank you so much, that was very helpful!